# getEffectiveOrgPolicy error on google cloud run secret mounted volume

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-secret-manager

Today when I went to deploy a new revision of a cloud run application I was unable to press the deploy key. No error or nothing just an unresponsive key.

I use secret manager and I have narrowed down the issue to the step where you add the secret mounted volume. When I do this, I receive the following error when I inspect the network.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

`{"constraint":"constraints/gcp.SecretManagerFilesystemAccess"}`

However, when I go lookup the constraints in the documentation, this constraint doesn't exist.

I do have some organizational policies set like refusing the ability to create service accounts, create service keys or upload keys, but I have confirmed that my other organization has the same settings and is having no trouble.

Does anyone from google have any information regarding this issue?

**EDIT:**

Steps to reproduce this issue.

1. Open Google Cloud Platform.
2. Click "Cloud Run" from navigation bar.
3. Select Service
4. Click "Edit and Deploy New Revision"
5. Open Inspector, click Network, clear current items.
6. "Select Variables and Secrets"
7. Click "reference a secret".

This produces the following error on url:

`https://cloudresourcemanager.clients6.google.com/v1/projects/PROJECTID:getEffectiveOrgPolicy?key=`

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
    "status": "NOT_FOUND"
  }
}
```

`{"constraint":"constraints/gcp.SecretManagerFilesystemAccess"}`

I can see this also produces a validation form error when the "Deploy" button is pressed that is not visible as well.

Comment: What is the output from **gcloud org-policies describe gcp.SecretManagerFilesystemAccess --organization=ORGANIZATION_ID** and from **gcloud org-policies describe gcp.SecretManagerFilesystemAccess --project=PROJECT_ID** Those commands should return the policy that contains that constraint.

Comment: 1. (gcloud.org-policies.describe) NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.

Comment: 2. API [orgpolicy.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [149547440894]. Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)? (y/N)?

Comment: After Y... `gcloud.org-policies.describe) NOT_FOUND: Requested entity was not found.`

Comment: I would open a support ticket with Google Cloud (paid) or on Issue Trackers (free) https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers If you are part of Google Cloud Insiders, post a message there.

Comment: What do you mean by **when I inspect the network**? Show the command that generated the error.

Comment: The CLI commands report the same error message as your question. Some detail is missing here. I would list each policy and review its details.

Comment: Command was done through the dashboard. I listed the steps to reproduce the error. I will review my policies to see if that is the issue.

Comment: Try deploying using the CLI only. That will usually provide more details on the error. You should also see details in Cloud Logging.

Comment: Will try that. One thing to note is that when I add the secret volume, it disables the "Show Command Line" button in the top corner. So I'll just add that code in but I thought that was interesting.

Comment: @JohnHanley So deploying from the CLI worked. Thank you SO VERY much for the recommendation and for pushing me to use the CLI. :)

Comment: That is good news. Please create an Issue Tracker for this item. If the Console GUI failed and the CLI worked, something is wrong internally I think.

Comment: I have filed an issue report. TY

Comment: Post an answer showing the command that you used to deploy. That way this question does not stay open. You can then update the answer as information develops from the Issue Tracker.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this using the following command in the CLI.

```
gcloud beta run deploy nightpricer-api \
--image=gcr.io/io-nightpricer-prod/nightpricer-api@sha256:d74ac81ced1628929075d6c8e97b039ac705663bf3a988cbb57bfad77a30a6dd \
--platform=managed \
--region=us-central1 \
--project=io-nightpricer-prod \
--update-secrets=/config/secrets=APP_SECRETS:latest,/config1/gmail=GMAIL_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS:latest \
--service-account=firebase-adminsdk-hbr00@io-nightpricer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

Comment: Your question mentions **Secret Manager** but your command does not use that service. I thought you had a constraint issue with secrets and constraints. I might have been helping you solve a different problem. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/secrets

Comment: I just was trying to omit information and accidentally cut it off. Fixed now. Actually looks like they solved the issue too.

Comment: Thank you. I bet someone noticed our thread and investigated what was going on. Sometimes these are just temporary self-correcting issues.